# Does not display any words in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, jsx

Here some images for you to check {

[Does not show any word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFlEJ.png)

[Even in Inspect Console there's no error shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRF7t.png)

Code in `app.js`:

```js
import React from "react";
import{
    BrowserRouter,
    Routes,
    Route
} from "react-router-dom";
import Add from "./pages/Add";
import Home from "./pages/Home";

function App(){{
    <div className="App">
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}></Route>
                <Route path="/add" element={<Add/>}></Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
};
}

export default App;
```

`Home.jsx` component code:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Home = () => {
    return {
        <div>Home</div>
    }
}

export default Home
```

It complied successfully yet and I can't see any error. Is there any I overlooked in syntax?

I tried to search for this solution but I can't find that perfectly work to my problem.

Comment: Please [edit] the post to include the relevant [mcve] as a propertly formatted and readable code snippet instead of links to images of code. Images are less accessible, can be more difficult to read, and are not copy/pasteable in terms of reproducibility.

Answer (score 2):

The `App` component needs to ***return*** a valid JSX value to render.

```
function App() {
  return ( // <-- return this JSX
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/add" element={<Add />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thank you! It worked! I guess I overlooked this since I debugged this for days.